# Move certain data from first column, to the last column on the row above

Tags: r

I have a data frame that comes in the following format

```
   c1  c2  c3
1   A   1   D
2   A   2   D
3   A   3   D
4   X   4   D
5   A   5   D
6   X   6   D
7   X   7   D
8   A   8   D
```

I need to make it so that any rows with "X" in `c1` are merged into `c3` of the row above, like below

```
   c1  c2        c3
1   A   1         D
2   A   2         D
3   A   3      DX4D
4   A   5   DX6DX7D
5   A   8         D
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the `c2` values unique as well? You could always use `dplyr` to `group_by` `c1` and `c2` then paste the `c3` column together?  Something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not provide your data structure,  it is unclear if c3 is a factor or a string.  Just in case,  I am converting it to a string before processing.

```
dat$c3 = as.character(dat$c3)
for(r in nrow(dat):2) {
    if(dat[r,1] == "X") {
        dat[r-1,3] = paste(dat[r-1,3], "X", dat[r,2], dat[r,3], sep="")
        dat = dat[-r,]
      }
}
dat
  c1 c2      c3
1  A  1       D
2  A  2       D
3  A  3    DX4D
5  A  5 DX6DX7D
8  A  8       D
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- read.table(text = "    c1  c2  c3
1   A   1   D
2   A   2   D
3   A   3   D
4   X   4   D
5   A   5   D
6   X   6   D
7   X   7   D
8   A   8   D", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

desired_output <- read.table(text = "    c1  c2  c3
1   A   1   D
2   A   2   D
3   A   3   DX4D
4   A   5   DX6DX7D
5   A   8   D", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rownames(desired_output) <- NULL

library(dplyr)
output <- 
df %>% 
  mutate(to_paste = ifelse(c1 == "X", paste0(c1, c2, c3), c3)) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c1 == "A")) %>% 
  summarise(c1 = first(c1), c2 = first(c2), c3 = paste0(to_paste, collapse = "")) %>% 
  select(- grp) %>%
  as.data.frame()

identical(output, desired_output) 
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

though already answered , i would like to explain stepwise my approach :

for this I'm using a different data :

```
# c1  c2  c3
#  A   1   D
#  X   2   D
#  A   3   D
#  X   4   D
#  A   5   D
#  X   6   D
#  X   7   D
#  X   8   D

y = which(df1$c1=="X")      # which rows are having "X"
z = cumsum(c(0,diff(y))!=1) # which of those are consecutive

# for the consecutive rows, paste all the columns data together
str <- sapply(unique(z), function(i) paste0(unlist(t(df1[y[z == i], ])),collapse = ""))

# which are the rows just occuring before these X's
z = unique(y[z])-1

# substitute the "pasted together" string at the rows just prior to X's 
df1$c3[z] = paste(df1$c3[unique(y[z])-1],str,sep="")

# subset to have only non-X's rows
df1[df1$c1!="X",]

#   c1 c2         c3
#1:  A  1       DX2D
#2:  A  3       DX4D
#3:  A  5 DX6DX7DX8D
```